# Why can't I log onto my wifi with my DS Lite?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-ds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No wifi connection on DS Lite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52528/no-wifi-connection-on-ds-lite)

I keep getting the "51300" error when attempting to connect to my wifi network. I'm positive that I've entered the WEP password correctly.

Comment: Does it give you any more information with the error?

Comment: I found the answer almost immediately after posting somewhere else on Arqade. I've added the answer just in case someone wants to know. Can you close this question or something?

Comment: this question doesn't need to be closed - self answering is totally okay. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No wifi connection on DS Lite](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52528/no-wifi-connection-on-ds-lite?rq=1)

I've found the answer. Try forcing your router's wireless mode into 802.11b.

Comment: Changing your wifi type to "mixed" or "b and g" should also work.

Answer (score 0):

Your employer may have MAC filtering in place to only allow certain type of devices.

Comment: "Your employer"? Who plays the DS at work?

Comment: I've been to people's houses who have forgotten they have a MAC filter enabled. That was a fun half hour of troubleshooting.